# Confused by very straight-forward "garage-door" problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

I'm somewhat embarrassed to ask this here as the problem seems to be so trivial and we (yes, I have been asking many people around me to pitch in - to no avail) always reach the same conclusion, which however is totally contradicted by reality, so ...

(Spoiler ... I think I've found the difference between reality and the problem description below.  I'll add it to the bottom of the question though - no use hiding my mistakes ;-) )

I have a garage door that stays inside of the walls.  I have no idea whether this type of door has a particular name in English, so to ensure we have the same understanding I'll add a picture and some explanation:

[image: cross-section of the garage door]

The garage door is one solid panel (typically of wood or with an internal metal construction) and has at the left and right sides a wheel at the top running inside a fixed (typically via some construction to the ceiling) horizontal rail and at the bottom a wheel running inside a fixed (to the side-wall) vertical rail.

Because of the rigidness of the door, I believe we can reduce this problem to 2D, so basically to the cross-section view given by the attached image.  As the wheels have some slack in the rails, they can roll inside them and hence I also think we can assume they won't provide any force in the direction of the rail, only perpendicular to it.

In most installations (as in mine) there will be a counter-weight installed which using cables pulls straight up at the point where the lower wheels are connected to the door.  Obviously the counter-weight would be such that the (manual) amount of force needed to open or close the door would be minimal ...

And this is where theory and reality clash.  If I call the mass of the door m and that of the counter-weight M, all my attempts indicate that choosing M = m/2 would have this door stand still in any position/angle that it can take, i.e. that it would never further lower or further rise out of itself if put (and shortly held) in that position.

Reality however shows that there is a point where the door is in balance and doesn't move on its own (if fully closed is 0 degrees, then my door seems in balance around 30 degrees - but I guess that might depend on the counter-weight), but that below this point (so more closed), the door further closes automatically and above that point (so more open) the door further opens automatically (and my arms can tell you that the force needed to counter this grows significantly the further you go from that balance point).  That seems to indicate that the force needed to counter the door's own weight should (unlike the constant weight of the counter-weight) be a function of the angle the door is at.  But as said, this is not what all my attempts to calculate that force result in.

Hence the question: can someone give a formula for the force one would have to supply vertically at the bottom attachment point of such a garage door in function of the weight of the door and the angle it is positioned in?  And also explain how you get to that formula.  Or otherwise explain why reality and simple mechanics calculations seem to clash here?

Adding some more info as it seems some people think the counter-weight would be something very special:
[image: Illustration including counter-weight]

As mentioned a steel cable starts at the bottom wheel at each side of the door, runs over a pulley at the top, so that the cable pulls vertically on that bottom wheel and then via a second pulley to the counter-weight.  In my case there is indeed a pulley for each cable attached to the weight and the cable then runs up and is fixed to the ceiling.  This just halves the distance the weight needs to travel and the force it applies to the door with its weight, but still that force will be constant over the travel of the weight (and hence the door), right?

Thanks in advance for help saving my sanity.

PS: the border case with the door fully closed also gives a hint that somehow the angle must play a role as it's easy to realize that in this position you will never get the door to open unless you also give it a sideways push.  So somehow that angle must have made the F needed to open the door infinite (fully countered by V), right?  Of course, that is not the F needed to keep the door in equilibrium, but still it raises that feeling that the angle does play a significant role, no?

==== NORMALITY HAS BEEN RESTORED ====

Or how oversimplification probably caused all my problems above ...
Looking a bit closer at the door, I started to realize that the center of mass of it is actually not in the middle between the wheels.  Hence a more correct sketch of the real situation would be:
[image: More correct problem description]
And when I then do a static analysis, I do get a $tan(\alpha)$ in the result and with the counter-weight slightly heavier than half the weight of the door, I also get a point between the extremes where the door would balance.

Conclusion: my original problem description is likely oversimplified in that it assumed the center of mass to be on the axis between the wheels.  The further that center of mass moves away from this axis, the more the position of the door plays a role.

Comment: Hmm... I detect the sweet whiff of homework.

Comment: Not at all.  Being 51 years old, the time of homework is long long ago.  As said, I am embarrassed having to ask it here, especially as I have an engineering degree (granted, in software science, but still, I did have mechanics as a course in the first years at university) and still this thing is killing my sanity.

Comment: Note also that this type of garage door is quite normal here (Belgium) and one of the problems it has is that having an automatic garage door opener for it is pretty difficult because of the force needed.  The alternative seen a lot (apart from sectional doors) is a variant where the vertical rail has a wheel attached at the center of the door.  That seems to require a lot less force and has automatic door openers, but has the drawback that the bottom part of the door then turns outside of the boundary of the wall, which impacts architectural options.

Comment: Do you know the know the weights? I'm just wondering if your w/2 issue is not really an issue here. If the counterweight is less than w/2, the behavior is basically explained with friction, which everyone here is just ignoring (you can tell I'm an engineer and not a physicist).

Comment: The answers so far seem to overly complicate things. I did a simple static equilibrium analysis (no net torque or force) and found the same as you: no dependence on the angle.

Comment: No angular dependence will fall out of m/2, but is that actually the mass of the counterweight? It is a function of the angle for any other counterweight mass.

Comment: I think we can assume that the counterweight will never be exactly the mass of the door, but I also think the people installing this type of door would prefer reducing the effort needed to open/close the door as much as possible.  As said, this type of door seems problematic at this, giving a lack of automatic door openers for it.  If adding/removing some weight can make the door easier to open, I'd love to figure that out as I can do that easily (the counterweight is an open metal box filles with metal filings and stuff).

Comment: @PoissonAerohead I explicitly phrased the question towards having a formula for the force to keep things in equilibrium.  That basically rules out any friction as there is no motion.  Still, above the balance point the requested force has to pull down and below the point you have to push the door up ...  In reality that is ... In my calculations, even for M != m/2 the force F would just be the difference between the two and hence constant irrespective of the position of the door - again clashing with what I experience in real life.

Comment: The title could use some work as "contradicted by reality" is just click-bait. "How does a garage door balance with a counter weight?" would be better since it not only describes what you're trying to achieve, it does so without trying click-bait people.

Comment: I agree with  @KyleKanos  The title is very misleading.  Your problem doesn’t contradict reality.  You analysis is just wrong… not exactly the same thing.

Comment: I am a bit stumped because for quasi-static conditions the load at each support point is indeed half the weight, and unless there is a spring involved somewhere this fact is independent of the door angle.

Comment: @KyleKanos & ZeroTheHero: I'm not a flat-earther!  I'm a strong believer in physics, but also in experimental proof and obviously there must be something wrong with my analysis or problem-definition and NOT with reality or the laws of physics.  The question here is: where is that flaw?  I don't want to change the title to "How does a garage door balance with a counter weight" as the real results from my garage door aren't matching any explanation given so far and if it would match, I would not be asking the question here.  That said, I might be zooming in on the reasoning flaw ...

Comment: @Mr.K - I stand by your decisions and your post. It is well-presented and researched.

Comment: @Mr.K - if you did indeed find a resolution, please post it _as an answer_ and even award it to yourself if you want.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou, I'll try to add the solution as soon as I have some time to do so (probably in the coming days).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the latest edit of my question, I think I have figured out the flaw in the original problem statement which could explain the difference between what my door is doing in real life and what the theory told us using that flawed simplified description.

Looking better at the door, I notice the wheels at the top and bottom of it are actually inset, thereby moving the center of mass to the outside compared to the plane through the wheels.  When changing the problem description to account for this, we get:

[image: Corrected problem definion]

The question still is to have a formula for a vertical $F(\alpha)$ (pointing upwards and working on the lower wheel - so basically adding to $M$) to keep the door still.  Simple static analysis now gives:

$$
Horizontal forces: H = 0 \\
Vertical forces: M+F = V+m \implies V = M+F-m \\
Torque: (M+F) (\frac{L}{2} cos(\alpha) - D sin(\alpha)) + V (\frac{L}{2} cos(\alpha) + D sin(\alpha)) = 0 \\
\implies (M+F) (\frac{L}{2} cos(\alpha) - D sin(\alpha)) + (M+F-m) (\frac{L}{2} cos(\alpha) + D sin(\alpha)) = 0 \\
\implies  (2M+2F-m) \frac{L}{2} cos(\alpha) - m D sin(\alpha) = 0 \\
\implies F L cos(\alpha) = m D sin(\alpha) + m \frac{L}{2} cos(\alpha) - M L cos(\alpha) \\
\implies F = m (\frac{D}{L} tan(\alpha) + \frac{1}{2}) - M
$$

Taking some (really) rough guesstimates for the lengths and weights: $L = 2m$, $D=0.1m$, $m = 200kg$ and $M = 105kg$ (forgive me for using $kg$ for force instead of the correct $N$ after multiplying with $g$ - it just reads more easily), this gives:

$$
F = 200kg \frac{0.1m}{2m} tan(\alpha) + \frac{200kg}{2} - 105kg = tan(\alpha)\ 10kg  - 5kg
$$

So, if the door would be almost completely open ($\alpha = 0\unicode{xB0}$), a downwards force of 5kg would have to be applied to keep the door from going open all the way.

And when $tan(\alpha) = 0.5$ the door would stand still on its own, so that would be around $26.5\unicode{xB0}$.  And above that angle (so more closed) the force needed to keep the door still increases very quickly thanks to that $tan(\alpha)$.  Now, with my door I get the impression the angle is more around $50\unicode{xB0}$, illustrating that my guesstimates for some of the values here are off from my actual door's values.

It also reflects that when the door is closed, you basically won't get it to open without some horizontal nudge as $tan(90\unicode{xB0})$ will become $\infty$.  This does reflect the "feeling" you get when trying to open the door.  You basically give it a horizontal push higher up to get it to open.  This also probably shows why you cannot just reduce the weight of the counter-weight and add a motor pulling extra on it to open the door.  I guess reducing the counter-weight and then adding a mechanism pulling horizontally at the top wheel might be a solution, but that's a different exercise ...

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways for this to work, so without actually looking at your garage door there is no way to give the correct answer.

I'll write $L$ the length of the door (length of the purple rod). I'll assume for simplicity that its center of mass in in the middle of the door. I'll also note $x$ the vertical displacement of wall joint, in particular $0\leq x\leq L$ with $L$ the length of the door.

The principle of virtual work says that:
$$
Fdx = dE
$$
with $F$ the force needed to apply at the moving joint to move it by an increment $dx$ and $E$ the energy of the system, in this case the potential energy of the door and of the counterweight, of mass $m,M$ respectively. You thus need only calculate $E$ as a function of $x$ and take the derivative to get $F$, which is what you want.

From geometry, you get:
$$
E = Mgx-mg\frac{x}{2}
$$
which gives your result.

Your observation indicate the presence of a single unstable equilibrium $x_0$. In terms of energy, this translates as a single global maximum. The simplest way I could think of is to modify the potential energy of the counter weight by making it piecewise linear rather than completely linear. Physically, the counter weight would be allowed to roll on a incline of variable slope, or something analogous. You could imagine a change of slope in the potential energy.
$$
E = \begin{cases}
-\frac{mg}{2}x+s_1Mgx & x<x_0 \\
-\frac{mg}{2}x+s_2Mgx & x>x_0
\end{cases}
$$
To reproduce your observation, you just need $s_1M< \frac{m}{2}<s_2M$. T'm pretty sure that your garage door must be more complicated than that. In general it is hard to guess what is going on, without knowing about the full apparatus, especially for the counterweight.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have added additional info on the counter-weight and as far as I can tell it will excerpt a constant force irrespective of the position of the door.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

From the work that done by the force $~F+M\,g~$ and by the force $~m\,g~$ you obtain

$$\int(F+M\,g)\,y\,dy=
 \int  (-m\,g)\,s\,ds\tag 1$$

with $~s=\frac L2\,\sin(\psi)\quad y=(a-L\sin(\psi))\Rightarrow$

$$ \left( F+Mg \right)  \left( a\psi+L\cos \left( \psi \right) 
 \right) =\frac 12\,mgL\cos \left( \psi \right) 
$$

solve this equation for force $~F~$   you obtain

$$F=F(\psi)
$$

---

with

$$[a=2,b=1,m=80,,M=32,g= 9.81]~,L=2.23~[m]$$

[image]

Comment: Although a formula with a cos(phi) in it looks promising, I don't feel this answers my question.  I was asking a formula for the force F to keep the door in equilibrium.  If I understand your calculation correctly, you express the energy I and the counterweight (basically its lost potential energy) would need to put into the system to compensate for the gain in potential energy of the door moving upwards, assuming constant F (considering your integration result) over that entire path.

Comment: From the energy equation, you obtain the force $~F~$ that you need to open the door. How you defined the equilibrium state ?

Comment: With "equilibrium" I just mean to hold the door in the current position.  If we put the door at an angle theta, then its weight combined with the counter-weight will make it move in some direction (or possibly not if everything is already balanced - but experimental tests with my door show that in most angles it is not in balance).  So my question is simply what extra vertical force F I need to apply at the lower wheel-attachment to keep the door from moving.  In tests this F depends on the angle the door is in, which contradicts my calculations.

Comment: @Mr.K see new solution

Comment: First I think it should be $~s=\frac L2\,\sin(\psi)\quad y=(a-L\sin(\psi))$ (so a, not b), but if F is a function of $\psi$, then I think your integration is wrong as it still considers F constant.  Also, I want to know the extra force to keep the door still and you calculate a force that would be needed to fully open the door (if I understand correctly what you are trying to do).

Comment: Sorry ,  but at each position of $~\psi~$ you obtain the the force F, that hold the door in equilibrium, there is no other solution

Answer (score 0):

> And this is where theory and reality clash. If I call the mass of the door m and that of the counter-weight M, all my attempts indicate that choosing M = m/2 would have this door stand still in any position/angle that it can take, i.e. that it would never further lower or further rise out of itself if put (and shortly held) in that position.

Can we see your analysis? Doing a basic static moment analysis at the upper wheel, I get

$$
F_{H}\tan(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}M_{d}g - m_{cw}g
$$

where $F_{H}$ is the horizontal reaction force, $M_{d}$ is the mass of the garage door, and $m_{cw}$ is the mass of the counterweight. The angle is measured from the horizontal, so that $\theta = 0$ when the door is fully open and we see the sensible result that no horizontal reaction is needed in that case. The formula above was found by solving for the reaction force (you call it $H$ in your picture) that would be necessary to give zero moment at that upper wheel for an arbitrary mass counterweight (not assuming half the door mass). As noted below, in general the door is not in equilibrium, so the real reaction force would be different and require a dynamic analysis.

Clearly for the special case of the counterweight equaling half the mass of the door, the horizontal reaction is unnecessary and the system balances for any angle. Otherwise, such angular balance would require a horizontal reaction, which would then push the door (there is no other horizontal force available) and thereby change the angle, meaning the system is not in static equilibrium.

Given this, I am wondering if the counterweight is a bit less than half the mass and this means that the weight of the pully system is non negligible. Beyond a certain point in one direction, the total mass is more than half the door mass, while beyond that point in the other direction, the total mass is less than half the mass. This variation in mass around the singularity at half the door mass would lead to the behavior you are seeing. This would show up in the above equation as $m_{cw}$ being a function of the angle $\theta$

Comment: I'm lost how you get to the formula in your first sentence and what the various variables are that you use.  I guess M<sub>d</sub> is the mass of the door (I used m for your M<sub>d</sub> * g) and that m<sub>cw</sub> is the mass of the counter-weight (without bothering with the extra pulley arrangement).  But what is F<sub>H</sub> (as I still had an F, H and V in my drawing) and how do you define your angle theta?  So, in general, can you elaborate on the "basic static analysis" giving you that formula?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, if having the counterweight exactly half the weight of the door would give a stable state over the entire range, then since both weights don't change, you should just have to add a constant vertical force F to compensate for the weight-difference if they are not the same, right?  So, then still you would not expect an angle in the formula for that F, right?

Comment: Yeah, to be clear I called it $M_{d}$ and $m_{cw}$ for the door and counterweight, and $F_{H}$ for the horizontal reaction force. I only did the moment balance, I would need to do a full one, but intuitively, if the counterweight is half the door weight, then the vertical reaction force will also be half the door weight and there is no horizontal reaction. It is intuitive to me that that would balance everywhere, and my equation says the horizonal reaction would be zero independent of angle (the tangent just divides out). I'll update this later with the analysis for you.

Comment: then I guess our calculations match, but my actual door doesn't want to comply.  I'll try to make a video this weekend with the actual door, details on how exactly it is mounted and how it has a unstable balance-point.  There must be something that breaks some of the simplifications made here, but I haven't found it yet, so maybe someone here notices something on the video.  Spoiler: the wheels are somewhat offset, so the center of mass is not in the middle of the wheel and not on the axis between the wheels, but even then I still don't get to an dependency on the angle ...

Comment: I thought through what the results show, and I would be interested if there is information on the door and counterweight mass. I am thinking that the mass of the pully system itself is moving the counterweight + pully system around that half the door mass point. That would lead to the unstable equilibrium behavior you are reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key here is that as the door opens, some of the weight of the door is held up by the top track and not by the counterweight. When the door is fully closed, the total force pulling up at the front edge must be equal to the full weight of the door to lift it. But when the door is fully open, only half the weight of the door is at the front edge, while the other half is at the back edge. A counterweight weighing more than half the weight of the door will hold the door open, but won't be enough to open it when closed.

The key empirical detail is how exactly the top wheel of the door starts to take the weight of the door. As the top wheel moves from its initial position, it bears some of the weight of the door, and the remaining force needed to keep lifting the door depends on that transition. In the closed configuration, both the top and bottom wheels on the door may bear weight anywhere between 0 and m, but both bear a weight of m/2 when the door is open by any amount - how that transitions occurs is unclear, but I believe  it's a key physical detail of this system.

Comment: The fully closed state is indeed a special case as not supply F to the bottom wheel to keep it not-moving will just be compensated by V (when drawn downwards as in my sketch) lowering to counter this.  Still, if I calculate things for any angle > 0 and < 90 degrees, I always reach that F+M = m/2 = -V (inverted sign because of how I drew V in the sketch).

Comment: @Mr.K Right, that's why I feel like there must be some transition dominated by practical effects in between the two stable states of fully closed pulling down and even slightly open pulling up. There must be some transition where the top wheels don't immediately take half the weight of the door the moment they start to slide back. The force from the counterweight seems pretty clearly constant, so it must be the fraction of the door weight that's unsupported by the top track that's varying.

Comment: Slightly open does not have the door close.  There is a third stable state (well, this one is probably only stable because of friction) around 30 degrees.  Below that point the door closes further, above that point it opens further.  And when trying to hold the door still above or below that point you can also feel that the force needed to keep it still increases away from that "stable" point.  Friction however won't make a still door move up at one spot and down at another, it will always resist movement.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that I think I found the source of where the dependence of the support force (from the counterweight) must vary by angle to get balance even for the simplified case initially presented.

The answer is *friction* of course.

Even though the door is on rollers, there is enough grease and grime usually on these rollers to present some friction, significantly affecting the support force required at shallow angles (measured from vertical for me).

[image: fig1]

<sub>In the image above, $A_x$ and $B_y$ are the rail reaction forces, and $A_y = \mu A_x$ and $B_x = \mu B_y$ the corresponding sliding friction forces. The counterweight force is $S$ and the weight is $W$.</sub>

The force/moment balance equations are

$$\begin{aligned}
 A_x + \mu B_y & = 0 \\
 S + \mu A_x + B_y -W &= 0 \\
 \tfrac{L}{2} \sin \theta ( B_y -S-\mu A_x) + \tfrac{L}{2} \cos \theta ( A_x - \mu B_y) & = 0
\end{aligned}$$

The solution for the support force is

$$ \boxed{ S = \frac{W}{2} \left( \frac{2\mu \cos \theta - (1+\mu^2) \sin \theta}{ \mu \cos \theta - \sin \theta} \right) } $$

The solution looks as follows for $\mu=0.1$

[image: fig2]

The above shows the opposite effect, where when the door is *almost* open at $\theta = 11°$ about, no support force is needed as friction is sufficient to hold the door up. But with the constant presence of the counterweight force, this means the door will try to open on its own, which is not what happens in real life.

The analysis is a bit complex because as soon as the door tries to open, the direction of friction switches. This results in a different curve that grows higher at lower door angles.

I have added below two sets of friction values, $\mu=0.02$ and $\mu=0.1$, as well as the two friction directions for a total of 4 curves.

[image: fig3]

Now this means to actually open or close the door completely you need to overcome friction whose effects grow larger the closer the door is to close.

This matches expectations as it is both hard to close and hard to open the garage door due to friction. But midway things can be balanced out and the counterweight is sufficient to support the door, and friction is less important as the curve approaches the $S/W = 0.5$ flat midline which is the ideal solution w/out friction.

Comment: I tend to agree that friction will change based on the angle and can indeed play a role in how much force is needed to open or close the door.  However, I feel to see how friction can cause the door to further open by itself when mostly open, yet with the same weight and counter-weight further close when mostly closed.  Friction will never cause things to start moving by themselves, so there must be some other force "flipping" between those two positions ...

Comment: @Mr.K - it is not friction that makes the door open, but the counterweight. As you can see in the FBD frictional force $A_y$ acts together with the support $S$. Basically, without a counterweight, the door can remain almost closed and friction is going to keep it there. With counterweight, the door is going to try to open but there won't be enough force to do so. So the door is just going to remain put. All this without consideration of the actual geometry which has the door center of mass offset from the support points.